# when filling a pdf document with pdfsharp, the filled form doesn't show the values unless the fields are clicked on

Tags: .net, pdf, .net-core, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

When filling a pdf document with **pdfsharp** (pdfsharpcore), the filled form doesn't show the values in the acrobat reader unless the fields are clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the values visible, I've inserted.

```
if (acroForms.Elements.ContainsKey("/NeedAppearances"))
    acroForms.Elements["/NeedAppearances"] = new PdfBoolean(true);
else
    acroForms.Elements.Add("/NeedAppearances", new PdfBoolean(true));
```

and it works.

Comment: Please be aware that the **NeedAppearances** key and the underlying functionality has been deprecated in PDF-2.0 (ISO 32000-2:2017).

Comment: so this wouldn't fix the issue of filled values not appearing in newer formats? @mkl

Comment: As soon as you have to deal with requirements for PDF-2 only, it wouldn't. Chances are, though, that in many contexts PDF-1 still remains relevant for a long time.

Comment: thank you for the helpful comments. Is there any equivalent in pdf-2 that does the same thing as the **NeedAppearances** flag?

Comment: No, there is no equivalent. A **NeedAppearances** value of `true` in ISO 32000-1 indicates to a PDF viewer that the appearance streams in the PDF file are missing or not up-to-date and, therefore, shall be re-generated by the PDF viewer. ISO 32000-2 on the other hand requires all annotations (form field widgets are annotations) to have up-to-date appearance streams. Thus, the **NeedAppearances** use case cannot occur in PDF-2 anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with same problem. Text appears only when I clicked to field.

```
var document = PdfReader.Open("pristupy.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
document.AcroForm.Fields[0].Value = new PdfString(user.LastName + " " + user.FirstName);
document.AcroForm.Fields[1].Value = new PdfString(unit.Name);
document.AcroForm.Fields[2].Value = new PdfString(system.Name);
document.AcroForm.Fields[3].Value = new PdfString(accessApplication.AppliedDate.ToShortDateString());
document.AcroForm.Fields[4].Value = new PdfString(roleAddString);
document.AcroForm.Fields[5].Value = new PdfString(roleRemoveString);

if (document.AcroForm.Elements.ContainsKey("/NeedAppearances"))
    document.AcroForm.Elements["/NeedAppearances"] = new PdfBoolean(true);
else
    document.AcroForm.Elements.Add("/NeedAppearances", new PdfBoolean(true));
document.Save("pdf.pdf");
```

Now its working correctly! (using PdfSHARP)